# Javascript string literal error

Tags: php

How would I maintain this code so that it doesn't break on a new line. As a result of this string being broken, I am getting a javascript string literal error.

I need to do this on the PHP side.

I've tried str_replace but that doesn't do it. I don't understand why the line is being broken in the first place.

```
CKEDITOR.instances.article.setData('<p>Test</p>
');
```

PHP:

```
$text = '<p>Test</p>';
```

Comment: You need to show the PHP code for use to tell you why it's broken in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript string literals cannot have unescaped newlines.

You need to call `json_encode()` before printing the string to escape newlines and other special characters.

Comment: This doesn't actually address the issue the OP is having. Read the question better.

Comment: I think that's not the question.

Comment: @Amber: I was still typing.

Comment: Actually suggesting `json_encode` to escape newlines is kind of neat, +1 for that.

Comment: No you don't, JSON is valid Javascript. However, you can get a Javascript error if there's something wrong on the PHP side, so maybe you want to encode it **twice** and then decode it with `JSON.parse()` on the JS side.

Comment: Let me try that now. As you can see from the PHP I posted up top, there isn't anything weird going on with the string so I'm not really sure where it's breaking the line.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help. This saved the day. :)

Comment: @SLaks - a suggestion, then - wait to hit "Post Your Answer" until you have an actual answer.